# OverlayItem looses focus when FragmentActivity Dismiss

Tags: android, overlay, android-fragmentactivity

I have a mapview with overlay items in it. These overlay can be tapped then show a fragmentactivity within the mapview. The problem is that when the fragmentactivity has been dismissed, mapview returns the focus to my current location. I want to return the focus on the tapped overlay item. How can this be done? Your answers will be highly appreciated. Thanks

This is the code I have but it isn't working.

```
final DefaultItemizedOverlay overlay = new DefaultItemizedOverlay(trafficProfileMarkerOverlay);

        final OverlayItem overlayItem = new OverlayItem(geopoint, "", "");      
        overlay.addItem(overlayItem);

        overlay.setTapListener(new ItemizedOverlay.OverlayTapListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTap(GeoPoint pt, MapView mapView) {
                Intent trafficProfileIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), TrafficProfilePopUpActivity.class);
                startActivity(trafficProfileIntent);overlay.setFocus(overlayItem);
            }
        });         
        mapView.getOverlays().add(overlay);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before your TrafficProfilePopUpActivity gets open , you can store your **GeoPoint** in some variable.

and when user comes to map activity you can use **CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition** to move map camera to your geopoint stored in variable before in **OnResume()** method.

Happy To Help.

Comment: Hi, i just discovered that mylocationoverlay disappear when animating to the tapped geopoint of the overlay item on onResume, what do you think is the problem? Here is the code: 

`code`

@Override
 protected void onResume() {
  try {
   
   if(overlayTappedGeopoint != null) {
    mapView.getController().animateTo(overlayTappedGeopoint);
} else {
myLocationOverlay.enableMyLocation();
myLocationOverlay.setFollowing(true);
myLocationOverlay.shouldAnimate(false);
myLocationOverlay.setBeaconAnimationOutlinePaint(null);
myLocationOverlay.setBeaconAnimationFillPaint(null);
}
`code`

Comment: I am not exactly getting your question. May be debugging your onResume catch the problem.

Comment: When i implemented your suggestion, myLocationOverlay (my current location) disappear but mapview animates to the geopoint of the tapped overlay item. I want myLocationOverlay to stay on the mapview as well